# Why doesn't EditText get focus with setFillAfter(true)?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

So when you have the visibility set to INVISIBLE on the `EditText` fields it doesn't want to get focus for the keyboard.

I fixed this issue by changing the visibility on those fields after the animation completes like this:

```
       edit_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       final Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_in_view);
       fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
       edit_text.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
       edit_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But I want to know *why* it doesn't get focus. Shouldn't `setFillAfter(true)` set them to visible again?

Comment: You can do it by calling `edit_Text.requestFocus();`

Comment: you did not start the animation or set the animation to the Edittext so even if that's true its not going to work in your case, secondly `View.GONE` is what i am certain that it will not make the Edittext get focus, but invisible i doubt.. i might be wrong though

Comment: JibranKhan I want to know why it doesn't, and will that force the keyboard to pop up? I would not want that behavior.  @Elltz it was a typo, invisible apparently does remove focus

Comment: what an animation does is it sets the alpha on a `View` to 0.0 & 1.0 and to me that is what `View.INVISIBLE`-(0.0) does since it takes screen space but its transparent,so i do not think its going to deprive it from view calls -(thats a thought) but i will take yours since you are certain, also requestFocus() does not necessarily means the keyboard will be forced up, it actually kinda does, it means that view can be focusable whether or not in touch mode.

Comment: Ok, cause I was looking at this question and he had the same issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221405/android-keyboard-wont-appear-for-edittext-after-animation-happens

Comment: `setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` on the ViewGroup the Edittex is in and see if it will make a difference

Comment: @Elltz That did not change anything

Comment: @Elltz I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886624/animation-setfillafter-before-do-they-work-what-are-they-for  it's pretty interesting!

Comment: you know what petro post your solution as an answer and rollback the edit, +1.. i guess your why has been answered

Comment: @Elltz all set, thanks again for the insight

Answer (score 1):

The description for `setFillAfter(boolean fillAfter)` says

> If fillAfter is true, the
>   transformation that this animation
>   performed will persist when it is
>   finished.

- When set to true it does do this
- An animation on Android does not actually animate the View itself, it
  animates a bitmap representation of the View
- Check out: [Animation.setFillAfter/Before - Do they work/What are they for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886624/animation-setfillafter-before-do-they-work-what-are-they-for)